# Problema em layout administrativo ao fazer login (Ao passar pelo ngIf o jquery deixa de funcionar)

Tags: angular

Estou tendo problemas com layout administrativo + login. Tanto o dashboard quanto o login estão no mesmo nível de aplicação.
Quando o usuário é redirecionado para o login ele abre a tela que contem 3 component header, menu e aplicação (Conteudo abre o login router-outlet) .

Etão fiz um eventEmitter para saber se o usuário está logado ou não, caso não esteja vou no app.component.html e removo o menu,header e rodape com ngif

```
<div id="container" [className]="mostrarMenu ? 'effect aside-float aside-bright mainnav-lg' : 'cls-container'" class="">

    <app-header *ngIf=(mostrarMenu)></app-header>
    <div class="boxed">
        <div  [id]="mostrarMenu? 'content-container':'content-container-login'"  class="aasdfasdfasdfasdf">
            <app-breadcrumb *ngIf=(mostrarMenu)></app-breadcrumb>

            <div [id]="mostrarMenu?'page-content':''">

                <hr class="new-section-sm bord-no">
                <div class="panel panel-body text-center">
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <app-config *ngIf=(mostrarMenu)></app-config>
        <app-menu *ngIf=(mostrarMenu)></app-menu>
    </div>
    <app-footer *ngIf=(mostrarMenu)></app-footer>
    <!-- SCROLL PAGE BUTTON -->
    <button class="scroll-top btn">
        <i class="pci-chevron chevron-up"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<app-snackbar></app-snackbar>
```

quando carrego a página e o mostrarMenu = true tudo funciona, mas quando o mostrarMenu = false e sou redirecionado para o login, eu informo as credencias e o mostrarMenu passa a ser true novamente aparecendo todo o layout, mas com um certo problema em sua funcionalidade :(

se no lugar no ngif eu colocar um [hidden] ele funciona, mas o usuario pode inspecionar elemento e voltar o menu header etc...

Alguma dica de como resolver? acho que seria interessante o login ser independente da aplicação admin.

Sei que não expliquei bem o problema, então segue o vídeo de 40 segundos mostrando o erro na pratica.

[Exemplo no youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmpX5SoJE7E&feature=youtu.be)

Segue app.routes

```
  import { Routes } from '@angular/router'

    import { LoginComponent } from './security/login/login.component';

    import {LoggedInGuard} from './security/loggedin.guard'

    export const ROUTES: Routes = [
        // { path: '', component: HomeComponent ,canLoad:[LoggedInGuard]},
        { path: 'login/:to', component: LoginComponent},
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './layout/home/home.module#HomeModule',canLoad:[LoggedInGuard],canActivate:[LoggedInGuard]},
        { path: 'mudar-texto', loadChildren: './mudar-texto/mudar-texto.module#MudarTextoModule',canLoad:[LoggedInGuard],canActivate:[LoggedInGuard]},

        { path: 'not-found', loadChildren: './not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule' ,canLoad:[LoggedInGuard]},
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala cara. Na verdade como você deve saber o ngIf remove completamente o código do DOM, enquanto o hidden simplesmente o esconde. O que deve estar acontecendo é que alguma lib que utiliza o jquery é carregada e executada quando seu app é carregado e, quando você coloca seu código novamente no DOM com o ngIf, a lib x não vai carregar/executar novamente na sua aplicação entendeu? Eu sei que não é o comum, mas o ideal não é usar jquery ou libs que não são adaptadas pro Angular, se não sempre vai ter que fazer algum tipo de "gambiarra" pra tudo funcionar como você espera.

Não tenho como ajudar muito porque esse problema é muito específico, teria que saber sobre o que você usa e quais pacotes estão instalados no seu projeto.

Abraço.

Comment: Meu problema é esse mesmo, Bruno. No momento, para resolver ao logar estou redirecionando para o / com window.location.replace('/') (com o coração partido hehe) no lugar do this.router.navigate(['/']). Obrigado.